# Append JSON elements in Ember

Tags: javascript

I am having an array with some of values (i.e., [1,2,3,4,5]), now i have to convert this array elements into JSON format.

I tries this one,

```
var Jsondata = {};
            for (i = 0; i < Response.get('firstname').length; i++) {
                Jsondata.push({
                    name : Response.get('firstname')[i]
                });
            }
 Ember.Logger.debug(Jsondata );
```

but it shows some error :

> **carousel.js:575 Uncaught TypeError: Jsondata.push is not a function(…)**

how to append json elements in ember?

Comment: it should be `jsonData = []` and not `jsonData = {}`

Comment: It might be easier to just do `Response.get('firstname').map(name => ({name}))`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "JSON format". As far as I can see, you are merely trying to create a JavaScript array of little Javascript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try like this.

```
var Jsondata = [];
        for (i = 0; i < Response.get('firstname').length; i++) {
            Jsonvalue = {
                   name : Response.get('firstname')[i]
            }
            Jsondata.push(Jsonvalue);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Jsondata` is a hash instead of an array. If you change it to an array your code should work. Your issue is unrelated to Ember